# Can I use Authorization header to authenticate to Amazon SNS, like I do when using S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I am trying to do a simple HTTP request which would publish a message to Amazon SNS. No SDKs, just plain `curl`.

I started by using the same approach that I used to access Amazon S3, that is to include `Authorization` header in the request. Here's an example of **working** code which downloads the list of files from S3:

```sh
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
name=$(basename "$f")
acl="x-amz-acl:bucket-owner-full-control"
string="GET\n\n\n$date\n/$bucket/"
signature=$(echo -en "$string" | openssl sha1 -hmac "$secret_key" -binary | base
64)

prefix="daily-$(date -u +"%FT%H-")"

echo "Downloading the list..."
curl \
    -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: $date" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${access_key}:$signature" \
    --connect-timeout 1 \
    "https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=$prefix&max-keys=10000"
```

Trying to do the same for SNS, this is what I got:

```sh
date=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
string="GET\n\n\n$date\n/"
signature=$(echo -en "$string" | openssl sha1 -hmac "$secret_key" -binary | base
64)

curl \
    -X POST \
    -G \
    -H "Host: sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: $date" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${access_key}:$signature" \
    "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" \
    --data-urlencode "Action=Publish" \
    --data-urlencode "TargetArn=$arn" \
    --data-urlencode "Message=Hello, World!" \
    --data-urlencode "Version=2010-03-31"
```

When I run the code, this is what I get in response:

```xml
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MissingAuthenticationToken</Code>
    <Message>Request is missing Authentication Token</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>...</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

The official documentation explains [how to authenticate requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html), presenting a very different approach that what I used to have for S3.

Why are there two approaches, one for Amazon S3, and the other one for, it seems, every other service?

Is there anything I can do to use for SNS the old approach I used for S3? Any parameter to add in the request to force it to use the old approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might be using [Signature Version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) for your S3 example.  This is based on your string to sign starting with an HTTP verb (GET in this case).

[Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) is the [recommended way to sign your requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html#signature-versions), and is what you linked regarding a different approach.

All services except for SimpleDB work with Signature Version 4, and so learning this new approach should allow you to generally sign your requests for (almost) any AWS service.